# Devise doing n+1 queries on login/logout user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested, mongoid

I have a rails 3/mongoid app where I login using devise, and everytime that happens (login or logout), not only User is loaded (which I expect), but all its profiles (4 of them) are also loaded by mongo. Like this:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=asgard_development collection=advertisers selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"51facd99615956fdb4000026"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.6170ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=asgard_development collection=publishers selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"51facd99615956fdb4000026"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7150ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=asgard_development collection=regular_users selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"51facd99615956fdb4000026"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5891ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=asgard_development collection=admin_users selector={"$query"=>{"user_id"=>"51facd99615956fdb4000026"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.6969ms)
```

That's too much! I imagined Devise was building the User object and also all its relations. But isn't that supposed to be lazy??

My User is like this:

```
class User

  ##Includes begin
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Roles
  ##Includes end

  ##Scopes begin
  ##Scopes end

  ##Constants begin

  ##Constants end

  ##Extras begin



  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :lockable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  ##Extras end

  ##Relationships begin
  has_one :admin_user
  has_one :regular_user
  has_one :publisher
  has_one :advertiser
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin_user, :regular_user, :publisher, :advertiser
```

I want to avoid doing n + 1(where n is the number of profiles an user can have) queries everytime a user signs in or out. And why is devise/mongoid doing it the hard way?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm using devise with mongoid on rails 3.2.13 and no such problem! What is admin_user, regular_user, publisher and advertiser?! Are they users?! Or something related directly inside the User? have you tried [Mongoid Indentity Map](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html)? Your server log about queries says that it loads exact same user 4 times!
As I see each of those nested models loads User instance of their own, so mongoid query that user for that instance! and that's the problem!

Comment: I think you have some validations on user which fire those queries. If you have trackable on user is saved on login/logout and will cause validations to run.

Comment: @KiT O: admin_user, regular_user and etc. are all profiles of an user. User is just the devise default user with email and password. Depending on the user profile, it has different fields and relations. One User could be admin and publisher for example. But it makes no sense that each nested model building an user model, because user is "the parent" in this case. It would cause an endless loop. And yes, I'm using Identity Map.

Comment: @rubish: I have no validations on my User model whatsoever. Though I have validations in the nested models (admin_user, publisher etc.). Could that be it? It validates only their respective fields. When I removed trackable though, it did only 1 query for user (which is correct). But I need the trackable data... =/

Comment: Why you don't use inheritance or at least user belongs_to profile relation (in case of multiple profiles this is not good idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that, like @rubish said well, the Trackable module from Devise saves the User object every time there is a login or logout. It explicitly uses the save() method. But why was it saving not only User, but searching all User's relationships and saving them too? Because I had an:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin_user, :publisher ...
```

And like the Mongoid documentation says:

> Note that autosave functionality will automatically be added to a
>   relation when using accepts_nested_attributes_for or validating
>   presence of the relation.

So autosave, which is not default behaviour in Mongoid, kicked in because of that line of code.

What I did to solve this problem was to put the **accepts_nested_attributes_for** inside each of my profiles models rather than User. 
I had to change the form where User was created with the profiles nested. Now the form creates a profile with a user nested.
For that to work, I had to override the Devise RegistrationsController to create the resource model differently. But that's another topic =)